# Obj-c Core Data fetch by categoryId in Array (which is a property of the managed object)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, nspredicate

I want to fetch products by Category id.
Because the products have an attribute called "categories", which is an array with the category id's, i do not know how to filter on this using `NSPredicate`.

Is it even possible? Or am I supposed to fetch all of them, and then iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store `NSArray` in core data, there is no `NSArray` data column type ...

Most likely you need to filter on the the category id field, in that case you can use `NSPredicate` in this way:

```
NSPredicate *searchFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id = %@", 67];
```

Comment: i have stored an NSArray as transformable... i guess i must make category object and reference it :S